# Why is IE cutting html list item attributes with slashes?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, cross-browser, html-lists

This is an odd one. I am trying to attach attributes to `li` tags that contain slashes, and only IE is cutting them off at the first slash. What I find interesting is that I have tried examining the behavior on other elements such as `span` and `div` tags and IE will not lose the value.

**example**

```
<span value="10/10/10">plain span</span> // value = "10/10/10"

<ul>
    <li value="10/10/10">plain li</li>   // value = "10"
</ul>
```

Inspect the elements in IE to see

http://jsfiddle.net/JLB9T/

Comment: for others - IE will retain the attribute value on a `ul li` element by forming the attribute as `data-value="10/10/10"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`value` is a special attribute on the `li` element that only applies when the `li` is a child of an `ol`. On elements such as `span` and `div` it is non-standard, but I wouldn't expect a browser to do anything funky with it when it is declared on those elements.

The [W3C HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) has this to say:

> If the parent element is an `ol` element, then the `li` element has an ordinal value.
>
> The `value` attribute, if present, must be a valid integer giving the ordinal value of the list item.
>
> If the `value` attribute is present, user agents must parse it as an integer, in order to determine the attribute's value. If the attribute's value cannot be converted to a number, the attribute must be treated as if it was absent. The attribute has no default value.

This is why, if you change your `ul` to an `ol`, [the list marker says "10"](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/JLB9T/2) (corresponding to the default decimal list numbering system).

However, the spec also says:

> The `value` IDL attribute must reflect the value of the `value` content attribute.

So while IE is parsing the attribute value as an integer (as should any other browser), it shouldn't be replacing the original attribute value given in the markup with the integer that is parsed from the original value as it appears to be doing. Other browsers correctly preserve the original value. Note that the value is still non-conforming as the spec says it must be a valid integer, which `"10/10/10"` is not.

If you meant to specify arbitrary data for your `li` element (or any other element), you should use a custom data attribute to ensure it doesn't clash with any existing attributes:

```
<li data-value="10/10/10">
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I should have specified that `value` is indeed arbitrary. I solved this with the comment of mine but this answer is helpful for a better understanding

Answer (score 0):

value property only works for ordered list, not unordered.

```
<ol>
    <li value="10/10/10">plain li</li>   
</ol>
```

Comment: I can not accept this answer. I need to use the `ul` element. I have found a simple solution I will post as a comment to solve this issue.